# Why does this simple program using std::rotate not compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

This *does not* work:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto it = std::rotate(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + 1, std::end(a));
}
```

The error I get is:

```
main.cpp:6:10: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
    auto it = std::rotate(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + 1, std::end(a));
```

This is clearly incorrect behavior, as the declaration of rotate is:

```
template<class ForwardIterator>
  ForwardIterator rotate(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator middle,
          ForwardIterator last);
```

Why does this simple program fail to compile?

Comment: Before C++11, `rotate` did not return anything. Apparently your standard library implementation is not completely up to date.

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) for libstdc++ ("rotate returns void.").

Answer (score 6):

Before C++11, [`std::rotate` used to return `void`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). So you're likely on a non C++11-compliant implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a `libstdc++` issue we can see this by doing a test using both `libstdc++` and `libc++` and we can see it only fails when we are using `libstdc++`.

Using [Rextesters online compilers](http://rextester.com/runcode) makes doing a quick test pretty simple, the [libc++  live version](http://rextester.com/ECR41842) generates no errors. While the [libstdc++ live version](http://rextester.com/SVC16117) generates the following error:

> error: variable has incomplete type 'void'

If we look at cppreference entry for [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) we can see the pre C++11 version indeed returned `void`:

```
template< class ForwardIt >
void rotate( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last ) (until C++11)

template< class ForwardIt >
ForwardIt rotate( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last ); (since C++11)
```

As indicated above in the comments this is apparently a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x):

> ```
> 25.3  |   Mutating sequence operations  | Partial rotate  | returns void.
> ```

Also, perhaps worth noting [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/UUH40627) has no problems with this code.